# Hazelcast monitoring tool

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to install monitoring tool for Hazelcast. Current I have 3 nodes which are configured but hazelcast monitor shows only one. Here is the configuration am using

```
<group>
    <name>consumer</name>
    <password>c0nsumer</password>
</group><port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
   <join>
         <multicast enabled="false"/>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <hostname>node1</hostname><hostname>node2</hostname><hostname>node3</hostname>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
   <interfaces enabled="false"/>
</network>
```

Answer (score 3):

First check if the nodes are clustering fine by looking at the logs of each individual node. If they are not clustered then it means your nodes have connection issues; meaning nodes are not able to connect over TCP with the provided hostnames. First try replacing 
`<hostname>node1</hostname>` 
with 
`<interface>node1-IP</interface>`. 
Make sure each node can '`ping`' the other nodes and port `5701` is reachable on each node.

If the logs are showing you that the nodes are clustered then obviously monitoring tool have issues. Since monitoring tool is no longer supported by Hazelcast Team, you should use Management Center product instead.

Comment: I am trying to get connection, initially it says
INFO: [test] 9001 accepted socket connection from /10.40.230.77:14423
but later it says java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:464)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.OutSelector$Connector.run(OutSelector.java:100)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.SelectorBase.processSelectionQueue(SelectorBase.java:102)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.SelectorBase.run(SelectorBase.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

Comment: Looks like one node1 can reach to node2 but node2 cannot reach node1. So check which IP:port each node started on and then see if all these IP:port addresses are reachable from each node. Make sure IPs can ping each other and ports are not used by any other process.

Comment: Thanks... One more help. I am trying to display map statistics on console. Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Hazelcast supports only 2 nodes in the FREE mode to monitor. If you are using the free version of Hazelcast you might not see some of your nodes in *mancenter*.

You should upgrade your Hazelcast license to be able to watch the Hazelcast instances. On the other hand, if the number of the nodes is the only case, they might increase the amount of monitorable nodes without upgrading your account if you get contact with their support. For more information you can check [here](https://hazelcast.com/products/#features):

You can also check if the nodes are clustered by checking the logs of Hazelcast. In the startup, it shows the number of active nodes in the logs.